# What kind of join can merge records in one single SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find and merge records in a table which are related by time. The table records user activity in a website (activity start and activity end times).

I am trying to merge down to one record any activity within an hour of other activity by the same user.  So if the start of one record is 55 minutes after the end of the same user's previous activity, I merge that down to make one record.

I've tried various kinds of self join to achieve this, but the results are never perfect.

In two steps, I have tried this:

1. First UPDATE the updated_at (activity end), so that all records within an hour of each other have a common updated_at timestamp, which is the latest of the group.
2. Delete all the later records in the group, so that only the earliest record remains, now with the earliest created_at and the latest updated_at

-- First set a common end-time (updated_at) for all activity by one user with less than an hour between

```
UPDATE users_activity
SET updated_at = (SELECT a.LatestEnd  FROM (SELECT
    UA1.id,
    MAX(UA2.updated_at) AS LatestEnd
FROM users_activity UA1, users_activity UA2
    WHERE
    UA1.id <> UA2.id
        AND UA1.user_id = UA2.user_id
        AND UA1.created_at > DATE_SUB(UA2.updated_at,INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
        AND UA1.created_at < UA2.updated_at
        ) a)
WHERE
    users_activity.id IN (SELECT b.id  FROM (SELECT
    UA1.id
    FROM users_activity UA1, users_activity UA2
    WHERE
    UA1.id <> UA2.id
        AND UA1.user_id = UA2.user_id
        AND UA1.created_at > DATE_SUB(UA2.updated_at,INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
        AND UA1.created_at < UA2.updated_at
        ) b);
-- next delete all the later records in the group, leaving only the earliest
DELETE FROM users_activity 
WHERE
    users_activity.id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT d.id FROM users_activity d 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
    COUNT(CONCAT(user_id,'_',updated_at)) AS Duplicates,
    CONCAT(user_id,'_',updated_at) AS UserVisitEnd,
    id,
    user_id,
    MAX(created_at) AS LatestStart
FROM users_activity
    GROUP BY UserVisitEnd
    HAVING Duplicates > 1) a on a.LatestStart = d.created_at AND a.user_id = d.user_id) as AllDupes);
```

If the data is like this:

```
|id  |user_id|created_at         |updated_at
|5788|1222   |2019-06-06 08:55:28|2019-06-06 09:30:41
|5787|3555   |2019-06-06 08:40:04|2019-06-06 11:07:21
|5786|1222   |2019-06-06 07:11:03|2019-06-06 08:01:29
|5785|7999   |2019-06-05 18:11:03|2019-05-01 18:17:44
|5784|3555   |2019-06-04 16:53:32|2019-06-04 16:58:19
|5783|9222   |2019-04-01 15:21:32|2019-04-01 16:53:32
|5782|1222   |2019-03-29 14:02:09|2019-03-29 15:51:07
|5774|1222   |2019-03-29 13:38:43|2019-03-29 13:50:43
|5773|7999   |2018-09-23 17:38:35|2018-09-23 17:40:35
```

I should get this result:

```
|id  |user_id|created_at         |updated_at
|5787|3555   |2019-06-06 08:40:04|2019-06-06 11:07:21
|5786|1222   |2019-06-06 07:11:03|2019-06-06 09:30:41
|5785|7999   |2019-06-05 18:11:03|2019-05-01 18:17:44
|5784|3555   |2019-06-04 16:53:32|2019-06-04 16:58:19
|5783|9222   |2019-04-01 15:21:32|2019-04-01 16:53:32
|5774|1222   |2019-03-29 13:38:43|2019-03-29 15:51:07
|5773|7999   |2018-09-23 17:38:35|2018-09-23 17:40:35
```

[image: Example of data for merging]

**New info**. This query will get me results containing the info I need: id of sessions to update and merge. But how to mass update, when each row's update potentially changes the updates needed on other rows?

```
SELECT b.id, b.user_id, b.created_at, b.updated_at, b.UpdatedAtOfSessionToMerge, b.IDofSessionToMerge FROM (SELECT
UA1.id,
UA1.user_id,
UA1.created_at,
UA1.updated_at,
UA2.updated_at AS UpdatedAtOfSessionToMerge,
UA2.id AS IDofSessionToMerge
FROM users_activity UA1, users_activity UA2
WHERE
UA1.id <> UA2.id
    AND UA1.user_id = UA2.user_id
    AND UA1.created_at > DATE_SUB(UA2.updated_at,INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
    AND UA1.updated_at < UA2.updated_at
    AND UA1.created_at < UA2.updated_at
    ) b order by b.user_id;
```

Comment: How do you know when and when not to merge? I see user_ID 1222 with 2 reocrds in the expected results.  Why is there 2 and not 1? ahh I see now hour w/in start

Comment: So if you have an entry at 1:00PM one at 1:45 PM and one at 2:15 PM and one at 3:15 are just the 1st two merged and the 2nd two merged?  or are all 4 merged  The rules on the merging are a bit Vague It would be easier to just group by YYYYMMDDHH24...  but I'm not sure this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for these clarifications. If there is a gap of more than one hour between sessions, don't merge. Gap means the time difference between updated_at (end) and the next (later) created_at (start).

Comment: Ok... so using my example above... the 1 & 1:45 would merge.  The 1:14 and 2:15 would merge the 2:15 and 3:15 would merge.  So my 4 records would become 3 with some being duplicated...  This isn't easy to do becuase the rules lack precision..

Comment: Right. Also not easy to do because each time a row changes (removing or updating a duplicate), we should recalculate the remaining results. I posted an answer here which does the job, but not elegantly. Still very interested if there is a cleaner way to identify and update batches of records according to their values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT min(ID) as ID, User_ID, Min(Created_At) Created_At, Max(Updated_At) as Updated_At
FROM Table
GROUP BY User_ID, DATE_FORMAT(Created_At, "%Y%m%d%H");
```

Would be close but I'm not sure I'm handling the "Hour" rollup the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can group your date based on a parameter. Also, it is always good in terms of future processing speed to order your data if you can. It also makes your query result just nicer.

```
SELECT min(ID) as ID, User_ID, Min(Created_At) Created_At, Max(Updated_At) as Updated_At
```

FROM Table
GROUP BY User_ID, 
ORDER BY User_ID;

[Check the following link for formatting dates in MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Comment: Keep in mind they want USER_ID to be listed multiple times if a user has different "HOUR" created_Ats...

Comment: True, alright yes I see what you did with the Date_format group by time also.

Comment: `SELECT min(id) as ID, user_id, Min(created_at) Created_At, Max(updated_at) as Updated_At FROM users_activity GROUP BY user_id;` Yes, that gets me the all-time first and last activity for each user. I need to group those into batches of records, separated by no more than one hour. That's still baffling me...

Answer (score 0):

This is a manual solution, good enough for a one-time clean-up of old session data. It uses two SELF joins, so there could be a more efficient way to do this.

**Step 1**, Find batches of session records and unify them by giving them all the same end-of-session value (updated_at)

```
UPDATE users_activity as u1 JOIN (SELECT b.id, b.user_id, b.created_at, b.updated_at, b.UpdatedAtOfSessionToMerge, b.IDofSessionToMerge FROM (SELECT
UA1.id,
UA1.user_id,
UA1.created_at,
UA1.updated_at,
UA2.updated_at AS UpdatedAtOfSessionToMerge,
UA2.id AS IDofSessionToMerge
FROM users_activity UA1, users_activity UA2
WHERE
UA1.id <> UA2.id
    AND UA1.user_id = UA2.user_id
    AND UA1.created_at > DATE_SUB(UA2.updated_at,INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
    AND UA1.updated_at < UA2.updated_at
    AND UA1.created_at < UA2.updated_at
    ) b order by b.user_id) as u2
    on u1.id = u2.id
    SET u1.updated_at = u2.UpdatedAtOfSessionToMerge;
```

Repeat this query until no rows are affected

**Step 2**, Delete unnecessary session records in each unified batch;

```
DELETE FROM users_activity 
WHERE
    users_activity.id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT d.id FROM users_activity d 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
    COUNT(CONCAT(user_id,'_',updated_at)) AS Duplicates,
    CONCAT(user_id,'_',updated_at) AS UserVisitEnd,
    id,
    user_id,
    MAX(created_at) AS LatestStart
FROM users_activity
    GROUP BY UserVisitEnd
    HAVING Duplicates > 1) a on a.LatestStart = d.created_at AND a.user_id = d.user_id) as AllDupes);
```

Repeat this query until no rows are affected